# how to push data into array in c

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to push , even numbers (firstly)then odd numbers into a same array (1 to N). Here i am trying to push even numbers first can not do it.Can anyone help me with this please?
array should be like this {2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9). n = 10 here

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int array[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            array[n] = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

I tried to push even numbers first into an array.But i failed to do that

Comment: When `n` is the size of the array, then valid indexes for the array are `0` to `n-1`. The statement `array[n] = i;` uses the index `n` and therefore accesses the array out of bounds, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Undefined behavior watch: what happens if `scanf` doesn't return `1` _or_ the user enters a number less than `1`?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a pretty simple problem. As other have noted, your big issue is assigning to the array out of bounds. Let's sidestep the I/O issues (always check the return value of `scanf`) by hard-coding `n`.

As we iterate, we simple need to offset the index for the array based on whether the number is odd or even. Odd numbers start at the index `n / 2` and then we add `i / 2`. This can be simplified to `(i + n) / 2`.

For even numbers, we just divide by two to get the index.

Consider `3`: we know it should end up at index `6`. `(3 + 10) / 2` => `13 / 2` => `6`. Or `4`: `4 / 2` => `2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 10;
    int arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
            arr[(i + n) / 2] = i;
        }
        else {
            arr[i / 2] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```